# In VS2017, how to display icon sizes for Xamarin IOS Assets?

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin IOS project, the `Assets.xcassets` does not show its corresponding icon sizes (e.g. 16x16, 20x20, etc). Is there a way to show these sizes ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQzHX.png)

Please check the above image. Before uploading any asset you can see size in the box itself. Once you've uploaded image, right click on specific asset and you'll get to know the size(scale * size) as shown in the image.